# Only show attributes that are present in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

In my show view I have a few attributes that aren't required to be filled in by the user. In my show view I can easily create a conditional like so:

```
<% if @user.occupation.present? %>
    <p><%= @user.occupation %></p>
<% end %>
```

But if I have 3 or more of these optional attributes, creating multiple conditionals for each of them can become very tedious. I thought of doing something like this but it turns out that the method `attribute` is private:

```
<% @user.attributes.map do |attribute, name| %>
  <% if @user.attributes.present? %>
    <p><b><%= name %>:</b> <%= @user.attribute %></p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

For security reasons I'm not necessarily trying to change the attribute method from being private but more so just looking for a way to list attributes of my model that have been filled in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% @user.attributes.each do |key, value| %>
  <% if value.present? %>
    <p><b><%= key %>:</b> <%= value %></p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: For your first solution I got the error `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)`

Comment: It's `@user.send(attribute)`, not `@user.send(:attribute)`. I fixed the code in both cases.

Comment: The only thing I'm finding now is that its only recognizing the attribute's value and not the name. So it reads `John Doe: John Doe` where it should read `name: John Doe`

Comment: Replace `name` with `attribute` where you expect the attribute name to be displayed.